# Error "Cannot resolve symbol 'mBlockLayoutRequests'"

Tags: java

In my class `ListView` I get the error message: "Cannot resolve symbol 'mBlockLayoutRequests'". (source code with error message: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K2Dw.png))

`mBlockLayoutRequests` is declared in my class `AdapterView` ([source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uVW7.png)), which is inherited by `ListView`:

```
boolean mBlockLayoutRequests = false;
```

When i click, I get the message "Cannot find declaration to go to". 
Is there an error in my code? What should i do to fix this error?

Comment: There are a lot of other errors in your code. Maybe you should post how both classes are declared (package, modifiers, inherit clauses), and the first few error messages, not an arbitrary error way down the code.

Answer (score 1):

The `mBlockLayoutRequest` field is package-private. If both classes are in different packages, then `ListView` cannot access this field. It has to be at least protected:

```
protected boolean mBlockLayoutRequest = false;
```

According to you screen shot, the `super` reference also has an error. Of course, make sure that `ListView` actually inherits from `AdapterView` (i.e. is neither private nor final).

Comment: thank you for my answer . ListView and AdapterView is in package android.widget  and mBlockLayoutRequest  is able to called by ListView.Class ListView can't access mBlockLayoutRequest  if mBlockLayoutRequest  is private, is it right ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Package-private field *are* accessible if both classes are in the same package. Only `private` fields are never accessible from outside.

Comment: yeah,you are right ! ListView actually inherits from AbsListView  that is  inherits from AdapterView. ListView and AdapterView is in same packet whose name is android.widget.you can search the two class use website  grepcode.com.the code is good ! but why it tip:"Cannot resolve symbol ...",what should i do for fix it ?

Comment: Is this library code that does not compile? Then, something else is wrong. Maybe a wrong compiler version. See my comment under your question and answer it by editing your question.